# Grow div from top right corner?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a grid of elements that need to be interactive. When one of the divs is clicked, it will grow to a larger size. For most elements "growing" a div from the bottom right corner is acceptable:

```
$(.my-div).animate({ width: "379px", height: "204px" });
```

However, there are some cases in which "growing" from the bottom right won't work with the rest of the application.

I may need to grow from the top-right, for example. Any ideas? I like the simplicity of animating to a new width/height, but I'm not sure if it can achieve an effect other than dragging from the bottom-right corner.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use absolute positioning, manipulate `top,left,width,height` attributes. There is no easier way

Comment: But that smooth transition (as if you're grabbing a window from the corner) would not be there, correct? Do you think there is any way to maintain the fluid animation?

Comment: There will be same transition. [See keyword "easing"](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could do it, either with jQuery animate like you mentioned, or CSS transitions. They would look something like

```
.child.clicked {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
-moz-transition: width 2s, height 2s;
-webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s; 
-o-transition: width 2s, height 2s; 
}
```

or

```
  $('.child2').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: ['300px', 'swing'],
    height: ['100px', 'swing']
      }, { duration: "slow", easing: "easein" });
  });
```

Here is an example to toy with http://jsbin.com/uxicil/1/edit

There are a number of easing properties and things to tweak until you get it exactly how you want.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for a quick & easy solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a detailed function for a client that is easy to put in whatever content you want.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/gschutz/393Cb/1/

```
function increase(event){
    $this = $(event.target);
    if( $(".bigger").length > 0 )
        decrease($(".bigger"));
    $fixed_corner = $this.attr("rel").split(":");
    if( !$this.hasClass("bigger") ){
        $new = $this.clone();
        $new.insertAfter($this);
        $new.css("position", "absolute").addClass("bigger");
        var offset = $this.position(), w = $this.outerWidth(true), h = $this.outerHeight(true);
        if( $fixed_corner[0] == "top" )
            $new.css("top", offset.top);
        else
            $new.css("bottom", offset.top-h);
        if( $fixed_corner[1] == "left" )
            $new.css("left", offset.left);
        else
            $new.css("right", offset.left-w);
        $new.animate({width: "+=50", height: "+=30", backgroundColor: "#eee"});
        console.log($fixed_corner);
    } else {
        decrease($this);
    }
}
function decrease($this){
    $this.animate({width: "-=50", height: "-=30", backgroundColor: "#aaa"}, 300, function(){$(this).remove();});    
}
```

you can add another ways to resize the objects.
just be careful to the size of the div's.